# Is it possible an already big table with jsonb doubled in size by just adding an empty jsonb property on each record? with postgres 12.7

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

We ran a migration on a table which contain a big jsonb.

"Just" one new attribute was added inside the jsonb: `"someAttribute": null` was added on each row.

After this migration, the "table_size" increase a lot: from 20GB to 50GB

It is normal?

These graphes show table size, dead-rows and autovacuums: [image: table size, dead-rows and autovacuums]

Tried to look at [TOAST behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/storage-toast.html), [vaccuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html), or [physical storage working](https://rachbelaid.com/introduction-to-postgres-physical-storage/).

Comment: Yes, this is normal.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
Can you please elaborate a bit more? Even involved key concept names are appreciated.

Comment: For example, will it double again if I add another attribute in the jsonb, or was it "this time only" because of some raised threshold that won't happen again?

Comment: If you did such an update again before the old space becomes available for reuse, you would expect the table size to become a little more than 3 times its original size (not another doubling which would be to 4 times the original size).  I say a little more, because obviously adding a key to a JSON make it take more space, as the key itself has some size.  How space is reclaimed for reuse is described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update a row in PostgreSQL, the old version of the row remains in the table, and a new version is added. So if you update all rows, the table size will approximately double.

There are two approaches:

1. After the mass update, run

   ```
   VACUUM (FULL) tab;
   ```

   But beware that the table is inaccessible during that operation.
2. Run the update in batches like

   ```
   UPDATE tab SET ... WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
   ```

   After each batch, run

   ```
   VACUUM tab;
   ```

   to remove the old data from the table. That `VACUUM` will not reduce the size of the table, but it will free the old row versions, and that space can be reused by the next batch.

Comment: Ok Laurentz, so I will run a full VACUUM when possible.
Is it normal that autovacuums did not reduce the table size? (There were 3 autovacuums during migration, please see the bottom right graph)

Comment: Yes, normal `VACUUM` (which is triggered by autovacuum) usually will *not* reduce the size of the table.

Comment: Thank you very much. full vacuum took 10 minutes on a staging database. We manage to run it on a low used moment. Next times we'll plan to use solution 2.
Regards

Comment: A subsidiary stupid question: our day to day activity updates many records. Did our disk usage increase due to this? There should be a mechanism that prevent it. Isn't the role of autovacuum? The seen effect of autovacuum is reducing "dead rows" only from what I am able to see.

Comment: That leads too far and would warrant its own investigation by a consultant.